# Beginner xcode/iphone webservices question

Tags: iphone, xcode

I aspire to create a button on my iPhone app, that when clicked, pings www.mysite.com/webInfo.php and receives a response.

My current programming skills extend to switching views and making pictures appear, and I'm not sure how to do this in a way that doesn't require opening a browser window.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Read up on the documentation of [NSURLResponse](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Base/Reference/NSURLResponse.html).

If you want to see what type of response you get, try getting the [status code](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Base/Reference/NSURLResponse.html#method%24NSHTTPURLResponse-statusCode) of the page.

Hope this helps, and good luck!

EDIT: Here's some example code:

```
NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com/"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30];

NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if(connection){
    //response
}else{
    //no response
}
```